# Estou com uma dúvida sobre criação de interfaces

Tags: python, tkinter, interface, back-end, aplicação-desktop

Estou com uma dúvida: Preciso aprender sobre criar interfaces(TKinter) no Python? Pois como o Python é backend imagino que criar interfaces não entra na parte de backend, ou entra?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Olá Renan! Boa noite.** A biblioteca do Tkinter serve exclusivamente para criar uma interface gráfica para um projeto ou aplicativo desktop.

****Há uso no desenvolvimento back-end?****

Imagino que não. Não consigo imaginar nenhuma situação da qual haja a necessidade de possuir uma interface gráfica no estilo do Tkinter no back-end.